# Запуск Node.js скрипта в качестве сервиса Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, daemon

Имется некий Node.js скрипт `prod.js`, который  запускает dev-сервер на определенном порту.

```html
const { execSync } = require('child_process')

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

const WEBPACK_PATH = 'node_modules/.bin/webpack'
const WEBPACK_CONFIG_PATH = 'internals/webpack/configs/prod'

execSync('yarn install --production=false')
execSync('rm -rf ./build')
execSync(`"${WEBPACK_PATH}" --config "${WEBPACK_CONFIG_PATH}"/webpack.prod.client.babel.js --display-error-details`)
execSync(`"${WEBPACK_PATH}" --config "${WEBPACK_CONFIG_PATH}"/webpack.prod.server.babel.js --display-error-details`)
execSync('node ./scripts/server/start-server.babel.js')
```

Есть ли возможность демонизировать его? Чтобы он делал следующее

- стартовал при физическом рестарте машины (очень нужно)
- реагировал на изменение файлов
- прибивал процесс по указанному порту

Нашел пару модулей: [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) и [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), однако, не вижу у них возможности автостарта при запуске системы.

Кроме того, попробовал [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), однако, команда

```
nodemon ./prod.js
```

Сваливается в постоянную перезагрузку, следовательно, процесс даже не может стартовать

```html
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node scripts/prod.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node scripts/prod.js`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
```

Кто сталкивался с подобной задачей, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Я не силён в windows, давно не имел с ним делов, просто из личного интереса хочу спросить - проблема в том, что вы не можете добавить программу в автозагрузку? И чем отличается `nodemon` от `fs.watch()`?

Comment: Там ведь вроде есть папка системная "автозагрузка". Вариант положить туда ярлык не подходит?

Comment: Простите если я что-то не правильно понял или невнимательно прочитал.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf нодовские скрипты разве так могут?

Comment: Автозагрузка не самый хороший вариант, ибо пока не войдёшь в систему он не запустится.

Comment: @while1pass nodejs - это обычная программа, значит её можно запустить через ярлык. Скрипт передаётся как аргумент.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf мне нужно запускать не ноду, а скрипт

Comment: @while1pass это как? Скрипт всегда запускается нодой. Он не может выполняться без интерпретатора.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf выполнить команду `node my-super-script.js`

Comment: @while1pass я вам об этом и говорю. Команда, которую вы написали, запускает программу "node", которой передаётся скрипт в качестве аргумента.

Comment: @while1pass попробуйте просто сделать ярлык на node.exe (где он у вас установлен я не знаю, в program files где-то), затем откройте свойства ярлыка и в параметрах укажите путь к вашему скрипту. Такой ярлык по идее будет запускать ваш скрипт в фоне. Останется только кинуть его в автозагрузку (хотя я точно не гарантирую, что всё будет работать как задумано, у меня нет винды, не могу проверить). Если вам нужно не в фоне, а с выводом, то нужно прописать команду в bat-файле и сделать ярлык на него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоватся [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows), там есть возможность делать нативные windows сервисы.

Comment: Да, сейчас работаю с этим пакетом, спасибо за комментарий

Comment: Если она станет недействительной то либо проект node-windows закрылся, либо закрылся github, создание сервиса под Node.js процесс ещё тот, тут коротким ответом не отделаться, потому что кроме установки самого сервиса в систему, для корректной работы нужно наладить его ответы в системный Event Log Windows

Comment: @while1pass для этих целей это самый нормальный вариант под Node, по крайне мере когда я искал это было так

Comment: @vnn198 надеюсь, все пойдет и смогу опубликовать расширенный ответ. с виду выглядит все просто - создавай обертку и вперед, про логирование даже не думал. есть вопрос, мы просто создаем скрипт их документации и запускаем его `node my-service.js`?

Comment: Из того что я тогда читал, для нормального функционирования скрипта он должен работать с Event Logging, иначе могут быть проблемы, в целом всё несложно, просто слишком много кода для ответа в рамках stackoverflow

Comment: @vnn198 есть примеры в репах или другом месте?

Comment: и вот этот код из документации, как мы должны использовать? прописать в js-скрипт, батник? немного не понятно, только пример кода и сразу показывает, что сервис в автозагрузке

Comment: библиотека позволяет прописать в сервисы запуск скрипта js с помощью NodeJS. И попутно позволяет нормально взаимодействовать со службой сервисов.

Comment: появилось два вопроса. вы упомянули про `нужно наладить его ответы в системный Event Log Windows`, куда буду попадать его ответы? в event Viewer? пока только вижу эвенты типа "скрипт, запущен, скрипт остановлен"

Comment: второй вопрос. создал файл с описанием запуска сервиса, который запускаю `node svc.js`, сервис появился. что происходит после запуска? он построчно выполняет все команды, описанные в исходном скрипте `prod.js`

Comment: Он работает как обычный скрипт, node-windows просто позволяет взаимодействовать с ОС, чтобы писать логи в стандартный event Viewe надо использовать nodewindows.EventLogger , подробно с примерами это описано в документации http://coreybutler.github.io/node-windows/manual/#!/api/nodewindows.EventLogger